# networking - Need help on Network Prefix and Pings

Tags: networking

VMS    _________         IP Address of eth0 __________           Network Mask

PC1    __________           10.0.1.100 / 24  __________       255.255.255.0

PC2    __________           10.0.1.101 / 28  __________       255.255.255.240

PC3    __________           10.0.1.120 / 24  __________       255.255.255.0

PC4    __________           10.0.1.121 / 28  __________       255.255.255.240

Results:

From PC1 ping PC3 -> successful

From PC1 ping PC2 -> successful

From PC1 ping PC4 -> error (100% packet loss)

From PC4 ping PC1 -> network is unreachable

From PC2 ping PC4 -> network is unreachable

From PC2 ping PC3 -> network is unreachable

---

Can someone explain why PC1 to PC4 is an error and why PC4 to PC1 is network unreachable?

Does it have to do something with network prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

All those addresses are in the `10.0.1.0/24` network. Putting different masks on them will cause you nothing but grief.

PC4 is in the network `10.0.1.112/28` so it can only get to PC1 through it's gateway, therefore it can't respond to the pings from PC1. PC1 thinks it's in the same network at the address of PC4, so you don't get the `network is unreachable` error, but PC4 can't respond so the ping times out.